# como agregar un elemento al final de un vector?

Tags: c

esta es la consigna:

Programe una funcion para agregar un elemento al final de un vector.
siendo v el vector al que se desea agregar un elemento, n la longitud maxima del
vector v, util un puntero a la variable que almacena la cantidad de elementos
actualmente utilizados de v, y elem el elemento a agregar.
La funcion debera agregar elem al final de los elmentos utilizados del vector v,
e incrementar el valor de la variable apuntada por util en 1.
La función debe retonar cero si pudo agregar exitosamente el elemento, y 1 en
el caso de que el vector v este lleno y no se pueda agregar el elemento al vector.

y esto lo que hice:

```
int agregar(int v[], int n, int* util, int elem){ 
    // Programar la funcion aqui
    for(n=0; n<*util; n++) {
        v[n]=elem;
        n=n+1;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
 }
```

mi duda es saber si esta bien planteada la consigna y como probar mi codigo con un vector?

Comment: osea que quito el return 0 y modifico ```v[n]=elem;``` por ```v[*util] = elem;``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para probar el código solo tienes que llamar a la función con los parámetros que espera.

Para eso necesitas crear al menos un arreglo y una variable que lleve la cuenta de los elementos que tiene.

Luego puedes imprimir las variables y los elementos del arreglo para saber si está funcionando como debería.

```
int agregar(int v[], int n, int* util, int elem){ 
    // Programar la funcion aqui
    for(n=0; n<*util; n++) {
        v[n]=elem;
        n=n+1;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    int n = 0;
    int vector[10];

    agregar(vector, 10, &n, 5);

    printf("El vector tiene %d elementos:\n", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d = %d\n", i, vector[i]);
}
```

Puedes ver cómo funciona [aquí](https://tio.run/##TVCxcoMwDN35infppQfBbWDoUqBb9@4pg88YqjuQW8dkyfHt1JiQVovkJ71nPamnTql5fiBW/dholGfXkHn@eosiYgfZWd1JGy/15VQLLAWHdMDoqF8R3eshuSKCj@MRH9Z0Vg7SopdoR1ZkGPJnpDDQGhtzlRXg8rBI@CJNE1xDc4nLietqkSzuEFec5n9Pq91oGdmKTNE/zE9N6@6DJI6TVTasjWpjBDtaOWNPeVYXUQA3r2tDIM8EHr3Xl@Q28G09r4137/2NDEeaNfZNOIBmZ86vn7wT4KTYrCLcjsLfPpVgn7zfu5dNdd8IeCqJbTOqvco0z78).

---

El código presenta varios fallos.

- Deberías usar `n` en conjunto con `*util` para saber si el vector tiene espacio. Al usarla como variable de iteración su contenido original se pierde.
- Si no registraste nigún elemento, `*util` debería valer 0. Por lo tanto el for no llega ni a la primera iteración y el elemento no se asigna. Así seguirá a menos que haya alguna modificación externa.
- Si `*util > 0`, el for estaría reemplazando todos los elementos por el que quieres agregar. Pero en el for hay un return. Así que solo podrá iterar una vez como máximo. Entonces, ¿por qué usar un for cuando el código en su interior se ejecutará solo una vez?
- Supón que se agregó el elemento. Pero no estás aumentando la variable que lleva la cuenta de los elementos. Así que estarás escribiendo el elemento siempre en el mismo sitio.

Arreglando los problemas y haciendo el código un poco más legible, quedaría algo así:

```
int agregar(int vector[], int maxN, int* n, int valor){ 
    // Si el vector ya está lleno se sale de la función
    if (*n >= maxN)
         return 0;
    
    // Se asigna el valor en la posición *n que corresponde
    // al elemento siguiente al último 
    vector[*n] = valor;

    // Se aumenta la variable que lleva la cuenta de los
    // elementos que contiene
    (*n)++;
    return 1;
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##TVBNb8IwDL3nV1ggUNNmqD3ssgK3XfcHWA9RmnaWWncKASEhfnsxSarNh/jrvWc75q03Zp7XSGa4tBb2Z9/itPs5CoHkQffO9tplr/hqjZ/cqVHwykZ9@wpRDhQrVz1MTt5BABt2kOUEx0MAylAL5qy/OIKyDqXwJOGcGjhElVqEBivIoojIxKtq8YirjRopk/c4jXNiclL9t21VNklsOSU2FFSlgi2v/i4T4Ncxr8tWn0Mig0dLFjYt2MGOlvx0/vimlQKScU7HmPA1GGaz2wOxK4q/gxfVTauAqaiWzbBhlcc8PwE).